# Cerrar Sesion Automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, sweetalert

Necesito colocar un temporirzador dentro de este mensaje de sweet alert pero donde tendria que colocarlo y como? aca tengo la opcion de continuar navegando en la funcion location.reload(); pero en el isConfirm que apareciera un temporizador de 30 segundos donde se cierra automaticamente la sesion.

```
  var timeout; 
    document.onmousemove = function(){ 
        clearTimeout(timeout); 
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            swal({
              title: "Tu sesión ha expirado",
              text: '',
              type: "warning",
              showCancelButton: true,
              cancelButtonText: "Continuar Trabajando",
              confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
              confirmButtonText: "Salir",
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            },
            function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url + "auth/logout",
                        type: "POST",
                        success:function(resp){
                            window.location.href= base_url;
                        }

                    });
                }else{
                    location.reload();
                }

            });
        }, 60000); 
    }
```

[image: Mensaje]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes colocarlo en el `$(document).ready()` de manera que en cada acción que recargue el DOM tu `setTimeout` se reiniciará, ya que te aseguras que la función no se ejecute hasta que la página este lista para ejecutar el código **javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //funcion
}
```

No se que tan flexible este tu idea, te sugiero usar [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading) y te dejo este ejemplo de su funcionamiento, puedes colocar tu código AJAX para que apunte a la función de tu controlador que mata la session y redirija a otra vista.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.confirm({
       title: 'Alerta!',
        content: 'La sesión esta por expirar.',
        autoClose: 'logoutUser|10000',
        buttons: {
            logoutUser: {
                text: 'cerrar sesión',
                action: function () {
                    $.alert('La sesión ha expirado');
                    //tu codigo AJAX                    
                }
            },
            cancelar: function () {
                $.alert('cancelado');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si lo tengo dentro de la funcion $(document).ready y funciona el resultado es este: https://imgur.com/a/mXaAQ

Comment: Pero la duda que tenia es como colocarle un temporizador digamos de 30 segundos donde automaticamente se cierre la sesion

Comment: 30s después que levante el confirm?

Comment: Antes del confirm, porque el confirm lo que hace es darle la accion al boton Salir, ahi cierra la sesion, seria cuando se muestre el Alert, no se si me doy a entender disculpa :D

Comment: Cuando el alert se muestre quieres por decirlo así un autoClose?

Comment: Algo asi mira: https://imgur.com/a/skt3X

Comment: Que tal Walter hace tiempo que no entraba aca al foro, pero volvi para la respuesta y si exactamente eso es lo que necesitaba, no habia ejecutado el codigo y a lo que me referia era que al terminar la cuenta regresiba que automaticamente destruyera la sesion, y regresar al login principal como haria eso?

Comment: Hola @WilsonicX, okey...deberías considerar redactar una nueva pregunta, obviamente sin mencionar lo que ya tienes solucionado, ya que según entiendo el alert funciona bien, ok!...pero no has destruido la sesión, y eso lo debemos hacer del lado de php, ya sea estes usando sesiones nativas de php o de codeigniter

Comment: Formulare una nueva pregunta :)

Comment: @WilsonicX éxitos en tu desarrollo

Comment: Ya formule una nueva pregunta deberias darle un vistazo gracias

Comment: como hago que si da click en cancelar se reinicie el contador, para que depues de ese tiempo definido vuelva a arojarme el mismo confirm.