# Mejorar estética de alertas

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, sweetalert

me gustaría mejorar la estética en la forma de enseñar una a alerta.

Tengo un formulario en un modal, que al pulsar en botón submit, después de validar los campos,  lo envio a un php que inserta los datos en una base de datos. Seguidamente, se notifica una alerta en la pantalla.

Este el el form

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validaCampos();">                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" type="text" placeholder="Edad"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"></input>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
               </form>
```

Este es el insertar

```
    <?php


        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 
        $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
        $edad = $_GET['edad'];
        $dir = $_GET['direccion'];                      
        $sql = $mysqli->query("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion) values ('$nom', $edad, '$dir') ");         

?>  

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
        alert("Contacto Registrado"); 
        </SCRIPT> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=listar.php">
```

De la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un segundo plano se actualiza la lista y no vas a ella hasta pulsa el aceptar.

Funciona todo bien, pero lo veo un poco "cutre" o anticuado. Vosotros que menejais el tema, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo más "chulo" o "moderno" la alerta de que ya se ha registrado el usuario?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) si deseas un ejemplo puedes ver [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145900/cerrar-sesion-automaticamente/145905#145905) puedes usar esta librería y es muy simple de implementar, puedes usar ya sea confirm o alert, leelo y me cuentas.

Comment: no puedes editar los `alert()` lo que tienes que hacer es usar tus propios alert o bien usar los de otras librerias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según tengo entendido no es posible aplicar reglas de estilos para editar los alert() o confirm().

Te recomiendo **SweetAlert, Alertify o BootBox**

```js
swal(
    "Buen trabajo!",
    "El contacto ha sido registrado!",
    "success"
   );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSA">Probar SweetAlert </button>
```

[Documentación Sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

**Alertify**

```js
alertify.alert('Buen trabajo!', "El contacto ha sido registrado!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/themes/default.min.css"/>
```

[Documentación alertify](http://alertifyjs.com/guide.html)

**BootBox**

```js
bootbox.alert("El contacto ha sido registrado!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

[Documentación BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-alert-dialog)

Answer (score 9):

Si sólo es el tema visual puedes usar [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), tiene diseños modernos y que se adaptan a 
distintas funcionalidades según necesites.

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {

  swal(
    '¡Genial!',
    'Mensaje de éxito',
    'success'
  )
})
```

```html
<!-- Swwet alert -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.16.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button>Un botoncito</button>
```

O también toastr para el manejo mas pequeño de validaciones , con mensajes 
pequeños [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/).

Página para editar toast [Editar Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

De igual manera te lo menciono aunque no lo preguntadste directamente, el código que muestras para dar el alta es altamente inseguro a inyección SQL y no deberías mandar data que no pase por un prepare antes; te dejo un ejemplo que pudieras revisar

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 

        $sql = $mysqli->prepare("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion) values (?, ?, ?) ");
        $sql->bind_param("sis", $nom, $edad, $dir);
        $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
        $edad = $_GET['edad'];
        $dir = $_GET['direccion'];
        $sql->execute();
```

Como puedes notar antes de que se manden directamente los valores se enmascaran con signos de interrogación y después hacen una especie de interpolación cuando en bindParam se los doy a conocer además de eso le indico con **s** que lo que recibe son cadenas de texto y con **i** con será un entero

Comment: ostiaaa muchísimas!! gracias enserio, esto es parte de mi TFG y me viene de lujo, ¿como puedo aprender más de estas cosas?, tu código funciona perfectamente!! Puedes darme más información? mil gracias

Comment: dame un momento y te paso una fuente de aquí de la plataforma solo que la encuentre

Comment: este recurso lo escribió @AlvaroMontoro moderador y me parece excelente para que tengas conocimiento efectivo del tema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!